# Given $2$ points $A$ and $B$, and a point $Q$ on the circle. Find the minimized value of $\frac{2}{3}\overline{QA} + \overline{QB}$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**Problem**

Given $2$ points $A(0,3)$ and $B(4,0)$ on the plane, and a point $Q$ on the circle $x^2+y^2=4$.

Find the minimum value of $\frac{2}{3}\overline{QA} + \overline{QB}$.

**My Idea**

Let $Q$ be $(2\cos{t},2\sin{t})$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{3}\overline{QA} + \overline{QB}
&= \frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{(2\cos{t}-0)^2+(2\sin{t}-3)^2})+\sqrt{(2\cos{t}-4)^2+(2\sin{t}-0)^2} \\
&= \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{13-12 \sin{t}} + 2 \sqrt{5-4 \cos{t}}
\end{align*}
Taking the derivative to find the mimimum:
$$\frac{-4 \cos{t}}{\sqrt{13 - 12 \sin{t}}} + \frac{4 \sin{t}}{\sqrt{5 - 4 \cos{t}}} = 0$$
However the computation is complicated. Are there another ways to deal with this problem?

Comment: it may be easier to do without polar coordinates, it will lead to similar derivative with roots but you'll get no sine or cosine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. It is geometrically pretty evident that the minimizing $Q$ lies in the first quadrant, so you just have to solve
$$ \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{5-4\cos t}}=\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{13-12\sin t}}\tag{1}$$
for $t\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. With such constraint $(1)$ boils down to
$$ \sin^2(t)(13-12\sin t) = \cos^2(t)(5-4\cos t)\tag{2} $$
which can be factored as
$$ (3\sin(t)+\cos(t)-2)(3\sin(t)-\cos(t)+2\cos(2t))=0.\tag{3}$$
The term $3\sin(t)-\cos(t)+2\cos(2t)$ is strictly positive for $t\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, hence the solution is provided by the solution of $3\sin(t)+\cos(t)=2$, i.e. by
$$ t=\arccos\left(\frac{2+3\sqrt{6}}{10}\right)\approx 20^\circ 47'48''.\tag{4}$$
The minimum value of $\frac{2}{3}QA+QB$ turns out to be $\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: and your solution should be easier? this is a joke!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: let users and the OP decide it.

Comment: the question is already decided, see the $-2$!

Comment: How to calculate $\frac{2}{3} \overline{QA}+ \overline{QB}$?

Comment: @StarChou: by substituting $\cos(t)=\frac{2+3\sqrt{6}}{10},\sin(t)=\frac{6-\sqrt{6}}{10}$ into your trigonometric expression.

Comment: Thank you! However, it is still not so easy to derive $t = \arccos(\frac{2+3\sqrt{6}}{10})$ from $3 \sin{t} + \cos{t} = 2$ for me. Could you explain this?

Comment: @StarChou: that is a standard trigonometric equation. $$ A \sin(t)+ B\cos(t) = C $$ is equivalent to $$ \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin(t)+\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos(t) = \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$ which is equivalent to $$ \sin\left(t+\arctan\frac{B}{A}\right)=\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}. $$

Comment: Thank you, I got it. However, I'm still finding a more "elementary" way to solve the problem, without using the result of trigonometry or calculus.

Comment: @StarChou: that is challenging, since the locus of points $Q$ such that $\frac{2}{3}QA+QB=\text{const.}$ is not a conic but an algebraic curve with degree $4$. By comparison, the [$3$-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) is an algebraic curve with degree $8$